# On Premise IBM MQ integration with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, ibm-mq, amazon-sqs

Is there a way by which we can do integration between On-Premise IBM MQ with AWS SQS/API Gateway.I checked lots of links but found that we can migrate whole IBM MQ to AWS MQ but can't call from AWS to on premise MQ. Please suggest if anyone has tried this kind of integration.

Comment: You would need a bridge between them.  For example it would need to read from AWS and write to IBM MQ.

Answer (score 5):

I’m assuming you have an AWS based application that integrates with SQS and an on-premise application that integrates with IBM MQ, and ultimately you want to communicate effectively between the two applications.
At a functional level IBM MQ provides a client interface and a bridge between this and the AWS SQS interface is relatively straight forward to create. One important aspect to consider is the non-functional aspects. The IBM MQ client can either communicate directly back to the on-premise MQ instance, or via an AWS MQ instance. Although it may appear to be more straight forward to communicate directly to the on-premise MQ instance there are a few considerations that may mean an MQ instance in AWS is a more sensible approach.

- Applications often use IBM MQ for its assured delivery capabilities,
  by building a bridge to AWS SQS which is a non-assured delivery
  provider there is a risk that messages can be lost or duplicated
  (depending on the implementation of the bridging logic). To minimize
  the chance of this occurring you want to ensure that you have a
  reliable network between MQ, the bridge and SQS instance. This
  removes any fragile network links, as MQ can transfer the message
  reliably from on-premise to a MQ instance deployed in AWS, overcoming
  any network issues transparently.
- The MQ Client is relatively chatty compared to two MQ instances exchanging messages. Due to the network latency between the on-premise and AWS data center, the chatty nature of the MQ Client can impact the overall performance of the solution.

Therefore, it is often sensible to install a lightweight instance of MQ within your AWS availability zone and allow MQ to transfer the messages from on-premise to AWS efficiently and reliably. To help get you up and running quickly, you can grab the IBM MQ developer container for free on DockerHub [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/).

Comment: Note for future readers - versions 9.3 onwards are on the IBM Repository https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=containers-mq-advanced-developers-container-image

Answer (score 0):

I created a SQS Adapter in the OnPremise server and called my SQS directly from there.